Update Role In asp.net core Idntity
I Use Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore in my project
When I try to update the user role I get the following error

InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type 'RoleEntity'
cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for
{'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities,
ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is
attached. Consider using
'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the
conflicting key values.

My Code :
public async Task<Result> UpdateRoleAsync(UpdateRoleCommand command, CancellationToken cancellation)
 {
 var model = await _role.Roles.AsNoTracking().SingleOrDefaultAsync(s => s.Id == command.Id, cancellation);
 if(model== null)
 {
     //To Do
     return Result.Fail(FailMessage.Internal);
 }
 var config = new TypeAdapterConfig();
 config.NewConfig<RoleEntity, UpdateRoleCommand>()
     .Map(a => a.Name, b => b.Name)
     .Map(a => a.PresianName, b => b.PresianName)
     .Compile();
 model=command.Adapt<RoleEntity>(config);
 
 var result=await _role.UpdateAsync(model);
 if (result.Succeeded)
 {
     return Result.Success();
 }
 string error = string.Empty;
 foreach(var item in result.Errors)
 {
     error += item.Description + "\n";
 }
 return Result.Fail(error);  
}


Get rid of AsNoTracking() in your second line.

Is your repository service registered as a Singleton ?

UpdateAsync method begins tracking the given entity but does not actually apply any changes to the database. Even if you were not getting this error, your code would not update anything. What you are looking for is SaveChanges which applies changes, but this relies on the changetracker. From the code you provided, it is difficult to tell where the entity first started to being tracked because you have AsNoTracking on the first query. You need to check wherever is calling this method and see where you selected the role first.

Your best bet will be to replace UpdateAsync with SaveChanges and see if it actually updated the role on the database. It probably won't work because the tracked entity is most likely not accurate and you seriously need to rethink your design.
